# Haskell: Highest sequence in a list that satisfies a predicate

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sequence

I want a function `takeUntill` with the signature `takeUntill :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]`.I did came out with the implementation but I'm looking for a cleaner solution to this problem than my existing one if it exists.
My current solution is :

```
takeUntill :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
takeUntill p a = snd $ maximum $ [(length x, x) | x <- groups p a]
groups :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
groups _ [] = []
groups p a = ((takeWhile p a):(groups p (drop 1 $ dropWhile p a)))
```

Comment: An input -> output example would help.

Comment: What do you mean by "highest sequence"? Should `takeUntil (> 1000) [1, 10000, 1, 10000]` return `[1]` or `[1,10000,1]`?

Comment: The shortest such sequence is trivial to get; the longest such can only be found for a  finite list, as you have to search the entire input to ensure you don't miss an element.

Comment: the name is absolutely no good, doesn't fit the code *at all.*

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you are doing this looks OK, but the `groups` function is messy - particularly the way you drop exactly 1 from the elements that don't satisfy p at each step, which can result in your result having a lot of superfluous empty lists inside it. (These of course won't affect `takeUntil` provided at least 1 element of `a` satisfies `p`, but they're still there.)

I would rewrite `groups` as follows, using some useful library functions:

```
groups p a = filter (p . head) $ groupBy ((==) `on` p) a
```

I don't know if it's more efficient or not, but I certainly find it easier to read. To give some explanation, `groupBy` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) is from `Data.List`, and splits a list into a list of sublists according to whether a function of 2 consecutive arguments is true or not. And `on` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) is a handy little function from `Data.Function` which feeds the result of another function to the inputs of a binary function. The result is that

```
groupBy ((==) `on` p) a
```

splits the list up into sections where `p` is always `True` or always `False`. Then we filter that into just the parts that are True.

Comment: your `groups` calls `p` twice for some elements. similar situation is with `sortBy (comparing f)`. it is solved with decorate-sort-undecorate pattern (cf. `sortOn`), which we can reuse here as decorate-group-undecorate: ``groups p xs = map (map snd) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ zip (map p xs) xs``.

Comment: Thanks, I'd only class myself as "advanced beginner" at Haskell so I'm happy for any help - although I did say that I had not idea if my version was efficient or not, and was only trying to make it more readable. (I feel your version is less readable than mine, although certainly much more so than the OP. One of my frustrations with Haskell actually is that it seems really hard to reason about performance, and most of the "tricks" which enable good performance seem to be at the expense of readability, which defeats what is imo one of Haskell's great strengths.)

Comment: speaking of performance, `zip` IIRC is a "bad producer" wrt list fusion. ``groups p = map (map snd) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst) . map (p &&& id)`` is better (I wanted to avoid the pointfree, using `zip`, for better readability -- the irony!). re: readability, reading from right to left often helps.

Comment: btw, my version also doesn't do the filtering. that was an omission on my part. it should be `... = map (map snd) . filter (fst . head) . ...`.